# Resque retry to perform a 'finally' function after several retries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have a resque job that is supposed to call a third-party API. I want this perform method to retry at least 3 times. If it still does not go through on the third try, I want it to send an e-mail to me saying that something went wrong and the API could not be called.

Is there a way to do this using resque-retry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [custom retry criteria](https://github.com/lantins/resque-retry#custom-retry-criteria-check-callbacks) to check how many times resque-retry has retried for you and do something different if the number is too large.  Something like this:

```
class APIWorker
  extend Resque::Plugins::Retry
  @queue = :api_worker_queue

  retry_criteria_check do |exception, *args|
    if retry_attempt > 3
      send_email

      false # don't retry anymore
    else
      true # continue retrying
    end
  end

  def self.perform(job_id)
    do_api_stuff
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

need's to add  @retry_exceptions = [] before the retry_criteria_check de

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ActiveJob with Resque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551550/2771889) you can use [ActiveJob's `retry_on` feature](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on).

```
class RemoteServiceJob < ActiveJob::Base
  retry_on(SomeError) do |job, error|
    # your custom logic
  end
end
```